# Site doesn't work right after moving from IIS 6 to IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, iis-7.5, mousehover

I have a site that I've copied over from an older box with IIS 6 to a new box running IIS 7.5. The starts up and goes to the login page just fine. After logging in, the next page comes up properly. But none of the menu items shown work anymore. Some items just lead to other pages and some menu items had drop downs child menus that show after hovering. Neither works anymore.

I've been through all the site settings a dozen times and I see nothing that's popping out at me. Please help!

Comment: Sounds like a JavaScript include problem. Can you put the path to your .js library (that's handling the menus) in the browser and download it directly? If not, you might be missing a virtual folder setting.

Answer (score 0):

How are the menus populated? Do they use an XML file that's in a directory that has the wrong permissions on the new box? Are they in a database that the new site can't see correctly?